# Swift/Firestore/Cloud Functions - Send message to a random user

Tags: swift, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm able to send a create a document in Firestore, but I wanted to know if there is a way to add n number of userIDs/user documentIDs in an array to that document from in swift or in Cloud Functions in typescript.

I understand I can query and get all the users from the users collection in an array and then get n random users to and add to the document to be created in Firestore but if I have a million users then that'll be a million reads and I'm trying to avoid that.

Code

```
    if let data = self.imageView.image?.pngData() {
        let postID = APIs.posts.collection.document()
        Services.storage.upload(path: "posts/\(postID).png", data: data, onSuccess: { (url) in
            Services.crud.create(
                ref: APIs.posts.collection.document(),
                dict: [
                    "createdAt": Date(),
                    "fromUser": APIs.users.currentUserRef,
                    "post": url,
                    "timer": 5,
                    //"toUsers": [userID1, userID2, userID3, etc...] <- How I want to end up in Firestore
                    "type": "Image"
                    ] as [String: Any],
                onSuccess: {
                    self.openCamera()
            }) { (error) in
                print(error)
            }
        }) { (error) in
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know all the IDs of the documents in a collection, you will still have to query the entire collection to get all the IDs.  There is no free "get all IDs" operation in Firestore.  There is no operation to find a randomized selection of documents.

Comment: Okay, that's what I assumed. Just thought I'd ask. Thanks! I just gotta find a work-a-round, aha.

Comment: You will need to code a solution yourself.  Try searching for "Realtime Database" instead of Firestore to get similar solutions, as they are both NoSQL databases with similar limitations.